# Implementing a camera relative to a planets surface / direction of gravity

Tags: java, opengl, camera, rotation, position

I am currently trying to implement an FPS camera function that will be relative to a set up vector.
In this case it will be the normal from a planets center to the players position.
This will enable you to walk around the planet. Without having the camera distorted by the curvature of the planet.

Currently, I use this to set the camera direction.

```
        Main.getMap().getLocalizedUpVector(shootPos, up);
        Main.getMap().getLocalizedAngle(shootPos, angle);

        matrice.rotate(angle.y, RenderElement.AXIS_YAW);
        matrice.rotate(angle.x, RenderElement.AXIS_PITCH);

        matrice.rotate(yaw,up);
        right.set(matrice.m00, matrice.m10, matrice.m20);   

        if(right.length()>0){
            right.normalise();
        }

        matrice.rotate(pitch, right);

        eye.set(matrice.m02, matrice.m12, matrice.m22);
```

It calls these functions.

```
public void getLocalizedUpVector(Vector3f pos, Vector3f res){

    res.set(pos.x - center.x, pos.y - center.y, pos.z - center.z);

    if(res.length() > 0){
        res.normalise();
    }
}


public void getLocalizedAngle(Vector3f pos, Vector3f angle){

    float deltaX = pos.x - center.x;
    float deltaY = pos.y - center.y;
    float deltaZ = pos.z - center.z;

    float distance = (float)Math.sqrt(deltaX*deltaX + deltaY*deltaY + deltaZ*deltaZ);

    float yaw = -(float)Math.atan2(deltaX, deltaZ);     
    float pitch = (float)Math.asin(deltaY/distance);

    angle.set(pitch, yaw, 0);
}
```

This implementation works fine for one half of the planet, but it messes up on the other side.
I suspect this is because of my getLocalizedAngle function returns values in a eulerian range.
But I am not sure, any solutions to this?

Comment: Sounds like the (probably apocryphal) story about the GPS-equipped fighter jets whose autopilot inverted them upon crossing the equator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured it out while working on something else!

```
        matrice.setIdentity();

        Main.getMap().getLocalizedUpVector(shootPos, up);
        matrice.m02 = up.x; matrice.m12 = up.y; matrice.m22 = up.z;

        matrice.rotate(pitch, RenderElement.AXIS_PITCH);
        matrice.rotate(yaw, up);

        eye.set(matrice.m02, matrice.m12, matrice.m22);


        if(eye.length() > 0){
            eye.normalise();
        }
```

First set the matrice to the up vector, then you rotate that vector by the global pitch axis to get pitch.
Rotate around the up vector to get the yaw.

Then you retrieve the relative eye from the matrice.